# Flowplayer requires an internet connection?

Tags: flash, windows-vista, flowplayer

I've noticed in testing a problem whereby Flowplayer will not play any content without a internet connection. All the files which make up my project are stored locally, and I've gone through and checked all the paths to make sure nothing points outwards towards the internet.

Curiously if I pull the internet connection out before the web page loads, the video file fails to load, however installing a loopback adapter gets around this. How can I alleviate this problem?

For proofs sake I've loaded the page in chrome looked at the network activity;

[image: chrome network activity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you need to set the security bit in the SWF file to play from a Local source.
See http://flowplayer.org/forum/1/29205#post-30262

Comment: If this is the problem, you can try running a local web server, even with the machine offline. Flash doesn't care whether you are online, just whether there is a "file:" in the url.